# How to filter out file names with certain prefix and postfix (extension)?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of files like this:

```
file_list = ['file1.zip', 'file1.txt']
file_prefix = 'file1'
```

I'd like to use `filter` and `re` to only get `file1.txt` above. I'm trying this:

```
regex = re.compile(file_prefix + '.*(!zip).*')
result = list(filter(regex.search, file_list))
# in the above, result should be populated with just ['file1.txt']
```

But the regex pattern is not working. Could someone help me out on this? Thanks very much in advanced!

Comment: Use: `re.compile(file_prefix + '(?!\.zip).*')`

Comment: Any particular reason to use regex for such a simple pattern match? It's a bit of an overkill...

Comment: @zwer What would you recommend to use instead of regex?

Comment: @user1330974 - Python's native string operations and list comprehension. Check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead like this:

```
regex = re.compile(file_prefix + '(?!\.zip)')
```

**Code:**

```
>>> file_list = ['file1.zip', 'file1.txt']
>>> file_prefix = 'file1'
>>> regex = re.compile(file_prefix + '(?!\.zip)')
>>> print list(filter(regex.search, file_list))
['file1.txt']
```

`(?!\.zip)` makes it a negative lookahead that asserts true when `.zip` is not present at next position.

[Read more about look-arounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain why we need to add `?!` instead of just `!'?

Comment: That's useful to know.

Comment: @anubhava Thank you so much for sharing more info!

Answer (score 2):

No need for regex for this solution - you don't need to bring a cannon to a thumb-fight. Use Python's native string search/check:

```
file_list = ["file1.zip", "file1.txt"]
file_prefix = "file1"
file_exclude = "zip"

result = [e for e in file_list if e.startswith(file_prefix) and not e.endswith(file_exclude)]
# ['file1.txt']
```

Should be considerably faster, too.

If you don't want to search for edges only and you want to filter out only entries that don't have the `zip` suffix after the `file_prefix` no matter where it is in the string (so you want to match `some_file1.txt`, or even `a_zip_file1.txt`, but not `file1_zip.txt`) you can slightly modify it:

```
file_list = ["file1.zip", "file1.txt", "some_file1.txt", "a_zip_file1.txt", "file1_zip.txt"]
file_prefix = "file1"
file_exclude = "zip"

result = [e for e in file_list if e.find(file_exclude) < e.find(file_prefix)]
# ['file1.txt', 'some_file1.txt', 'a_zip_file1.txt']
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing an alternative approach. I wonder if `find` (and even `starts/endswith`) are using regex-like approach in Python back scene. But I have to agree that not using regex is easier for most reader to understand and probably more performant like you said.

Comment: It doesn't use regex, it uses pure C string manipulation (something the regex engine uses as well, but it first needs to load the whole engine, compile the pattern, create branches...) Bottom line, you should use the right tool for the job - on many occasions regex will make your life easier (and in some cases it will work much faster than what you can do through Python string manipulation alone) but this is not one of those cases.

Comment: Thank you for the additional explanation!